# Javascript filter array by another array of filters

Tags: javascript

I have a filtersArray which is a bunch of {id, value} and I want to filter my data (also array of JSON objects) to get back only the elements that match all of the filters? Is there a better way to do this than iterating through the arrayOfFilters with each filter using a for loop and doing a filter on each criteria?

the data is an array of JSON objects - ie

```
[{formID:1234, name:"sam", email:"sam@gmail.com", status:"open", phone: "333-444-5555"},
 {formID:2155, name:"charlie", email:"charlie@gmail.com", status:"closed", phone: "888-323-1234"},...]
```

and the filtersArray `[{"status":"closed"}, {"name":"charlie"}, {"id":2155}...]`

I have tried doing

```
for(var criteria in arrayOfFilters){
   this.data = this.data.filter( d => d.status === criteria.status)
                    .filter(d => d.name === criteria.name)
                    .filter(d => d.address === criteria.address)...
}
```

it does not work real well since criteria is a JSON object like {"status":"closed"}, {"name":"charlie"}...

Comment: Show what have you tried so far in terms of code

Comment: Can show your arrays

Comment: updated with more details

Comment: Please add an example of the filters array.

Comment: why you need to check all criteria, there is an id that is used for that i think...

Comment: @FrancescoBellavita  i want to find all the objects in my data array that match all the parameters given in the filtersArray - i may or may not be given an ID. 
For example a user may want to filter this list based off of the address, and/or name etc. and not a specific unique formId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the idea is to find all items of source array that match (by all properties) with some item of filter array, you can go like that:

```js
const srcArr = [{formID:1234,name:"sam",email:"sam@gmail.com",status:"open",phone:"333-444-5555"},{formID:2155,name:"charlie",email:"charlie@gmail.com",status:"closed",phone:"888-323-1234"}],
      filterArr = [{status:'closed', name:'charlie'}],
      result = srcArr.filter(srcItem => 
                  filterArr.some(filterItem => 
                    Object.entries(filterItem).every(([filterKey, filterValue]) => 
                      srcItem[filterKey] == filterValue)))
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

If your filter is a plain object, that's even more simple:

```js
const srcArr = [{formID:1234,name:"sam",email:"sam@gmail.com",status:"open",phone:"333-444-5555"},{formID:2155,name:"charlie",email:"charlie@gmail.com",status:"closed",phone:"888-323-1234"}],
      filterObj = {name:'charlie', status:'closed'}
      result = srcArr.filter(srcItem => 
                Object.entries(filterObj).every(([filterKey, filterVal]) => 
                  srcItem[filterKey] == filterVal))
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Looking closer, the answer is a bit off. Your filterArr is an array of object of strings when it should be an array of objects which each have a separate string. ie

[{"status":"closed"}, {"name":"charlie"}, {"id":2155}...]

Comment: @Linkx_lair : if source array objects should match to **every** object of `filterArr`, simply replace `some()` with `every()`. You didn't really need to revoke your accept I would gladly support you with above solution, so the comment was pretty enough to draw my attention ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need this I believe, Find the key in the filters object and compare it to every record you come across in your data object. Once you have the key you can easily check the values

```js
const arrayToFilter = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'sam'
}, {
  id: 1,
  status: 'open'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'ana'
}];
const data = [{
    formID: 1234,
    name: "sam",
    email: "sam@gmail.com",
    status: "open",
    phone: "333-444-5555"
  },
  {
    formID: 1234,
    name: "mara",
    email: "sam@gmail.com",
    status: "open",
    phone: "333-444-5555"
  },
  {
    formID: 1234,
    name: "eugen",
    email: "eugen@gmail.com",
    status: "close",
    phone: "333-444-5555"
  }, {
    formID: 1234,
    name: "kevin",
    email: "eugen@gmail.com",
    status: "close",
    phone: "333-444-5555"
  },
  {
    formID: 1234,
    name: "ana",
    email: "eugen@gmail.com",
    status: "close",
    phone: "333-444-5555"
  }
]


const result = data.filter(x => {
  return arrayToFilter.some(y => {
    const key = Object.keys(y)[1];
    return y[key] === x[key]
  })
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I want to get an array of objects from data that match all the criteria in arrayToFilter. There is a redundant 'name' attribute in the arrayToFilter - which should result in no matches as it is an invalid filter. Other than that it looks real interesting

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = arrayOfData.filter( 
                     data => arrayOfFilters.map(d =>d.status).includes(data.status))&& 
                             arrayOfFilters.map(d =>d.name).includes(data.name))&&
                             arrayOfFilters.map(d =>d.address).includes(data.address) )
                                 )
```

Or

```
let result = []
for(var criteria in arrayOfFilters){
 result.push(this.data.filter( d => d.status === criteria.status && 
                                    d.name === criteria.name &&
                                    d.address === criteria.address)...
}
```

Comment: Thanks hamid. 
The issue i am running into is if there is an empty criteria attribute like no name. 
ie if the arrayOfFilters has a status or address but no name, then the filter doesn't return the object even if the other attributes match it. 
Is there a way to do this using maps and filters and other array functions more dynamically instead of using the for loop?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do after viewing an empty criteria attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if id is unique u can do:

```
const filteredArray = arrayOfData.filter( data => arrayOfFilters.map( filter => filter.id ).includes( data.id ) )
```